# Creating an empty index in elasticsearch in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, elasticsearch

I am using offical elasticsearch npm. In my node app i am creating index using that client as follows

```
client.create({
   index: orgID, ---------->This is dynamic
   type: "places",
   body:{}
   }, function(error, response){
         if(error){                                    
         } else {                                                           
         }                                                        
   })
```

I need to PUT MAPPINGs for the above index, So for that i have to create an empty index(index without data) first and then i have to execute put mappings and then i have to put data into index.

So for that i have to create an empty index, but in offical elasticsearch client the above method(create) is written in "`POST`" method so its expecting an body.

For that i have to give an empty body {} as above. So how can i create an empty index using official javascript client. Please share your ideas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another way to go about this is to use [index templates](http://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.5/indices-templates.html). The idea of index templates is to let ES automatically create a missing index whenever needed, i.e. when you're indexing a document whose index name matches some pattern and also apply a pre-defined mapping (+ eventually aliases) to that new index.

For instance, you can create an index template like this:

```
curl -XPUT localhost:9200/_template/template_1 -d '{
    "template" : "your_dynamic_index_name_pattern",
    "settings" : {
        "number_of_shards" : 1
    },
    "mappings" : {
        "places" : {
            // mapping definition of your places type
        }
    }
}'
```

When that's done, anytime you will index a new document (e.g. using your `client.create()` example above) whose index name matches the pattern, ES will create the index automatically and also PUT the mapping, before indexing your document.

Comment: thanks. But the your_dynamic_index_name_pattern is not defined it can be anything, i cant predict the pattern. Then how can i do this?

Comment: So what you're saying is that your index name can be anything arbitrary and it doesn't follow any naming convention ? Can you give some examples of what names you'd use? Also, do you have only that kind of randomly named indexes in your cluster or do you have some other indexes with fixed names, too?